# Pull data from db after form submission

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, forms

I have a very simple problem which I would like you to help me with. I have a form which I want to submit WITHOUT page refresh. Once the form is submitted SUCCESSFULLY, the content should display in a div somewhere on the same page WITHOUT page refresh!

NB. The form should be disabled UNTIL form is submitted. Here is what I currently have.

html:

```
<form action="<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post">
              <input type="hidden" value="12345" name="id" />
              <input type="hidden" value="123456" name="mid" />
              <textarea name="comment">Write something...</textarea>
              <input type="submit" class="submit" name="submitComment" value="Post Comment" />
              <div id="spacer"></div>
            </form>
```

php code:

```
if (isset($_POST['submitComment'])) { do something }
```

Comment: NB. The form should be disabled UNTIL form is submitted. What exactly do you mean by this?

Comment: well, to prevent repeat pressing of the submit button, it should be disabled until it's submited! Basically what i want to do is how commenting works here! You click, it disables, posts the comments, shows the comment on the page all without refreshin the page!

Answer (score 0):

Without refresh... only jQuery / Ajax could do this job.

http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/submit-a-form-without-page-refresh-using-jquery/

Comment: this isn't what am looking for! This only submits the form and replaces the form with something else. I want a form to submit to a database but shouldn't hide and then another div pull that data afterwards and then display it inside the div!